# Ansible cycle over a list with count

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given a count, let's say `5`, and a list of strings `['string1',string2','string3']` I want to cycle through the list of strings for the given number of times. The expected output would be `['string1',string2','string3','string1','string2']`.

I think this is a similar idea as to what `loop.cycle` does [in jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#cycler), however, I want to use this in the playbook as a value to a key, not in a template. Is there any typical way of accomplishing this? If I need to make a custom filter_plugin that wouldn't be a big deal I suppose but want to know if the feature is already there.

The actual use-case I'm intending is to be able to match a given list of subnets with a count of hosts to provision an arbitrary count of hosts to span the list of subnets. The resulting list would be used by a `with_indexed_items` loop probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    mylist:
      - string1
      - string2
      - string3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mylist[item|int % 3] }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end=4
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I ended up with a slight modification:

`---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    count: 5
    mylist:
      - string1
      - string2
      - string3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mylist[item|int % mylist|length] }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ count - 1 }}`